# Python beginner help input error handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am just starting to learn Python and am trying to handle errors a user might input. All the program does is use the math module, asks the user for an integer and returns the factorial of the number.

I am trying to catch errors for negative numbers, floats and text.

If I enter an integer the code runs like it should.

When I enter a wrong value, like -9 or apple, the try/except seems to not catch the error and I get the traceback information. The user shouldn't see this.

Any suggestions or pointers?

```
import math
from datetime import datetime
import time

num = 0
start = 0
end = 0
# max value is 2147483647
#if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
except OverflowError:
    print("Input cannot exceed 2147483647")
except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a non-negative whole number")
except NameError:
    print("Must be an integer")
else:
    start = datetime.now()
    print("The factorial of ", num, " is : ")
    print(math.factorial(int(num)))
    end = datetime.now()
    print(f"Time taken in (hh:mm:ss.ms) is {end - start}")
```

I am using Python 3.10 on a Windows 10 Pro (64-bit) PC if that matters.

Norman

Comment: Why do you think any of those exceptions will be raised automatically by `input()`? It looks like you may have gotten some information from Python 2.x, which automatically evaluated the response to `input()`. In Python 3, it just returns it as a string.

Comment: You need to put the `try` around the line of code where the error will actually occur. Right now you're only checking for an error if the `input` function isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is missing the operation which can cause the exception: in fact, `input('...')` returns a string representing whatever user inputs. This means that your `num` variable is a string (you can check by printing `type(num)`. 
You have to try to cast it into an integer:

```py
try:
   num = int(input('...'))
except ValueError:
   print('invalid input')
```

Be carefull: if user input the value "-3", it will be accepted: the string will be cast into the integer `-3` and this is correct. 
If user inputs words like `'apple'` or floats like `3.14`, the exception raised is `ValueError`. 
My suggest is to do something like this:

```py
try:
   num = int(input('...'))
   if num >= 0:
      # computing factorial
   else:
      print('error: only positive numbers will be accepted')
      return
except ValueError:
   print('invalid input')
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because input() do not raise an error just because you want just a number. You have to check the type of input by yourself and then also raise an error by yourself.
e.g.

```
if not isinstance("string", int):
    raise ValueError
```

edit: also have a look here for more information about input(): https://www.python-kurs.eu/python3_eingabe.php
It always returns a string, so you have to convert your input actively in the type you want and make your type check during/after the conversion

Answer (score 0):

I took the path yondaime offered and got pretty close to what I wanted. The final result is below.

I thank all of you for your comments. The last time I did anything even slightly like programming was in Fortran on punch cards on an IBM 360.

I apologize for asking such basic questions but really am trying.

The code that works but really doesn't point out exactly which fault happened. I will try to figure out how to convert the string in the input statement to a float and see if there is a remainder (modulo maybe?) so the user gets a better hint what was wrong.

```
import math
from datetime import datetime
import time

num = 0
start = 0
end = 0

try:
   num = int(input('Enter a positive whole number: '))
   if (num >= 0 and num <= 2147483647):
       start = datetime.now()
       print("The factorial of ", num, " is : ")
       print(math.factorial(int(num)))
       end = datetime.now()
   else:
      print('Number must be between 0 and 2147483647 are allowed.')
      print(f"Time taken in (hh:mm:ss.ms) is {end - start}")
except ValueError:
    print('Text or decimal numbers are not allowed. Please enter a whole number between 0 and 2147483647')
```

I have a lot time to learn because I'm bored in retirement ...

Norman